# WPF using and accessing an ObjectContext from the BackgroundWorker thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke, ui-thread

I have a code like the following (I have stripped some code for readability)

```
    private void RicercaArticoloStripped(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new ControlloSchedeLocalEntities())
            {
                var prodotti = context.VProdotti.Where(i => i.WACMAT == textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text);

                if (prodotti.Count() > 0)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        textBlockDescrizioneArticolo.Text = prodotti.FirstOrDefault().WADESC;
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:\n\n" + ex.Message + "\r\nStack: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void textBoxCodiceArticolo_KeyUpStripped(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(RicercaArticoloStripped);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RicercaArticoloWorkerCompleted);
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);

            object[] parameters = new object[] { textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text, textBlockDescrizioneArticolo.Text };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
        }
    }
```

So, as for my understanding of BackgroundWorker, when I instantiate the:
var prodotti = context.VProdotti.Where(i => i.WACMAT == textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text);

I am doing it FROM the working thread, not the UI thread.

But I get an exception on the line immediately below, when I try to access the value:
if (prodotti.Count() > 0)

I get the (in)famous error:
**"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"**

Why?

Comment: You are accessing `textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text` from non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already said you must use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke/Invoke` to perform operations from the control's owner thread or you will get **"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"** exception. Thats why you got this exception;

And here is why you got this exception on the line below (when `prodotti.Count()` was called):

When you create `prodotti` variable it's just a `IEnumerable<T>` object. So he actually calculates only when you call for `prodotti.Count()` method and thats why you got exception on this line.

`IEnumerable` actually is generator, that means that he will produce new set of objects every time he used.

To test this you can calculate `prodotti` as shown bellow:

```
var prodotti = context.VProdotti.Where(i => i.WACMAT == textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text).ToList();
```

In this case you will get exception immediately because .ToList() forces all calculations.

Check this article for generators and enumerators: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155462/IEnumerable-Lazy-and-Dangerous

Updated:
really, when you use IEnumerable with reference types you can get the same objects as previously. Read this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361094/1467309

Comment: Ooops... It was my mistake, effectively I have been misled from the "Lazyness" into thinking the problem was on accessing the ObjectContext, while in was in accessing the TextBox.text indeed !

Answer (score 0):

The property `Text` of `TextBox` gets the value of the `DependencyProperty` `Text`, this can only be done from the UI-thread. You are accessing `textBoxCodiceArticolo.Text` from your Worker thread.