# Why isn't the change to a field in an IEnumerable executed?

Tags: c#

This was a surprise to discover that the following call didn't seem to remember the changes made to the field.

```
private void Foo(IEnumerable<Blopp> blopps)
{
  foreach (Blopp blopp in blopps)
    blopp.SomeField = PREFIX + blopp.SomeField;

  String test = blopps.First().SomeField;
}
```

The *test* variable lacks the prefix when the array is obtained using LINQ to data. I need to evaluate the *IEnumerable* and make it a *List* in order to make the changes to the fields sustain. Why is it so? I would expect the program to recognize that the field **is** used later on and evaluate it.

```
private void Foo(IEnumerable<Blopp> _blopps)
{
  List<Blopp> blopps = _blopps.ToList();
  foreach (Blopp blopp in blopps)
    blopp.SomeField = PREFIX + blopp.SomeField;

  String test = blopps.First().SomeField;
}
```

Comment: What is `_blopps` an `IEnumerbale` onto? Making it a list might resolve an otherwise dynamically generated `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @SteveB It's a type delcared by a *class*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you pass into it. If it's a *lazily evaluated sequence*, then each time you "look" at `blopps`, it will re-evaluate the input.

If you pass in something like a `List<T>`, the sequence will contain the same exact values each time, so that's fine. If you pass in an unmaterialized query, it will execute the query each time you look at the input. Whether that returns references to the same objects as the previous evaluation will depend on exactly what it's doing.

(As noted in comments, in some cases, changes to the objects returned by one evaluation could even change the results of the query completely - the objects could be modified in such a way that they then don't match filters earlier in the query.)

Comment: I assume he has a query which filters on the field he wants to change and he's changing that in the `foreach` what also changes the result of the query. However, that should decrease `Count()` of the sequence every evaluation and should not result in a wrong result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That's another possibility, yes. Basically all kinds of things depend on the exact nature of the input.

Comment: Darn... Is it recommended to execute *ToList* in order to protect against that? Is there a better method?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It depends on too much information that you haven't provided, so we couldn't say.  Do you actually need to access the information again, or are you just verifying that it was set?  In that case it may be working as is, you're just not correctly seeing that it's working.  Whether or not your changes are being applied or ignored depends mostly on where the `IEnumerable` comes from.  Detailing that goes a long way to getting a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Servy Then I'm in a picle. I get the object served and can't tell any more details. Moreover, I've noticed that some of the elements actually retain the change performed in the loop and others don't. A strange creature, that *IEnumerable*. I'll try to find out how it's built up.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's not `IEnumerable` that's strange, it's the implementation.  It could be implemented any number of ways, some of which are easy and some of which are hard to understand (and some of which are arguably just wrong).  Since you don't know anything about how it's implemented, there isn't any way for us to address that.